Stable Diffusion A1111: Difference Between sampler_name and sampler_index in img2img and txt2img Payload Parameters
I am using Stable Diffusion A1111 for img2img and txt2img tasks, and I have encountered two payload parameters: sampler_name and sampler_index. What are the functions of these two parameters, and what are the differences between them? In which situations should I use one over the other?
Specifically, I would like to understand the following:

The exact purpose of the sampler_name parameter
The exact purpose of the sampler_index parameter
The differences between these two parameters
Scenarios where one parameter might be preferred over the other

What I Tried:
I have been working with the Stable Diffusion A1111 interface and tried using both sampler_name and sampler_index parameters in my img2img and txt2img tasks.
What I Expected to Happen:
I expected to see clear differences in the output images based on which parameter was used, and to understand how each parameter affects the sampling process.
What Actually Resulted:
However, the results were not as clear-cut as I anticipated. I'm having trouble distinguishing the specific roles and impacts of sampler_name and sampler_index on the final images. This has led to confusion about which parameter to use in different scenarios.
